# could not run laravel de vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

`$ npm run watch`

> master@1.0.0 watch C:\xampp\htdocs\master
>   npm run development -- --watch
>
> master@1.0.0 development C:\xampp\htdocs\master
>   cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"
>
> Sistem belirtilen yolu bulam▒yor.
>   events.js:167
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>   Error: spawn node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js ENOENT
>       at notFoundError (C:\xampp\htdocs\master\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
>       at verifyENOENT (C:\xampp\htdocs\master\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
>       at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\xampp\htdocs\master\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
>
> Emitted 'error' event at:
>       at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\xampp\htdocs\master\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! master@1.0.0 development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the master@1.0.0 development script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\ikize\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-12-16T15_24_49_086Z-debug.log
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! master@1.0.0 watch: `npm run development -- --watch`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the master@1.0.0 watch script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\ikize\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-12-16T15_24_49_117Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js ENOENT at notFoundError

it seems that you haven't install `webpack`.

since you are using `laravel`, you should have a package.json file usually it comes with `laravel-mix` which will install webpack. run `npm install` to install node modules.

if you just want to install `webpack`

run `npm install webpack --save`.